# Прижать Button и CheckBox к нижнему краю

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Есть такая разметка. Необходимо кнопку и чекбокс прижать к нижнему краю (в самом низу прижатый к нижнему краю кнопка, над ней прижат к кнопке чекбокс), а чтобы txtTranslation занимал все оставшуюся часть в центре. Как это сделать?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/backgroung"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/linearlayout"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fLayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/fLayout1"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txtWord"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/linearlayout"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Введите слово"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:padding="@dimen/padding_inputs" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnClearForAdd"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
                    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                    android:onClick="onClearBtnClick"
                    android:padding="@dimen/padding"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_clear" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtTranslation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/fLayout2"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
                android:background="@drawable/linearlayout"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:hint="Введите перевод"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:minHeight="290dp"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_inputs" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/sendCheck"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtTranslation"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
                android:background="@drawable/linearlayout"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:text="Сообщить разработчику" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_height"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                android:layout_below="@+id/sendCheck"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
                android:background="@drawable/button_style_nocolor"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:onClick="onClickAddButton"
                android:text="Добавить слово"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вынести их за пределы `ScrollView`. Возьмите `RelativeLayout` или какой Вам нравится и разместите в нем:

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
    <ScrollView ...>
        ... 
    </ScrollView>
    <CheckBox .../>
    <Button .../>
</RelativeLayout>
```

`Button` к нижнему краю, `CheckBox` к `Button`, `ScrollView` на все свободное пространство.

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую